# Read Puppet json facts in Php

Tags: php, arrays, json, puppet

I can't read a json file from Puppet facts.

This is an extract of the file :

```
is_pe => false
is_virtual => false
kernel => Linux
kernelmajversion => 3.10
kernelrelease => 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
kernelversion => 3.10.0
load_averages => {
  15m => 16.73,
  1m => 15.62,
  5m => 16.15
}
memory => {
  system => {
    available => "52.59 GiB",
    available_bytes => 56470835200,
    capacity => "57.90%",
    total => "124.91 GiB",
    total_bytes => 134120931328,
    used => "72.32 GiB",
    used_bytes => 77650096128
  }
}
```

Usually I have no problem reading Json file using my code below, but I don't know why for this one I am not able to do it.

This code doesn't return me anything, no datas and no errors :

```
$fileName="puppet_facts.json";

if (file_exists($fileName))
{
    //$content = file_get_contents($fileName);
    //$content = utf8_encode($content);
    //$result = json_decode($content, true);
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);

    print_r($result);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file extract shows that you have facter's default output in the file, and not JSON data.

If you need JSON formatted facter output, try:

```
facter --json
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't noticed that, shame on me. Thanks for your help it works now.